# Is it necessary to resolve the errors shown in the output window of Netbeans IDE even if my code is working the way I want?

Tags: java, netbeans, compiler-errors

Say I want to get the 'of' typed in the input by the user

I am making an app, not finishing off in this dumb output screen (This is only an example)

```
 import java.util.*;
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 String text = input.nextLine();
 int check = 0;
 for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++;){
     if(text.substring(i, i + 2) .equals("of")){
          check = 0;
     }
 }
```

If the user enters `abofd`, it surely recognises the of at position at 2-4.
But when `i` value is 4 it checks position from 4-6, but as position 6 is not present is not present it gives an error.
I know you are thinking me to set `i < text.length() - 1` at line 5, but my original code needs to run until the end!

Comment: Are you getting runtime errors or compile time errors? Netbeans wouldn't mark a runtime error, yet you tagged this as runtime error.

Comment: sorry compile time errors

Comment: How do you know your code works if these are compile time errors? Wouldn't your code not compile?

Comment: I have another code which is a calculator, It checks every character in the textArea for +-*/ and of. So If it goes beyond range then i will know that it can't track space (2 characters) for the word 'of'.

Answer (score 1):

It is always a **good** idea to validate input coming from a user, but you are very much overcomplicating things! Even worse, you wrote down outright **wrong** code:

```
String text = input.nextLine();
int check = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++;){
   if(text.substring(i, i + 2) .equals("of")){
```

The above **can't** work! You see, *i* iterates from 0 to text LENGTH. But then you are using i+2 to get a substring from text. (so: say hello to your first ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException).

Instead, you can do things like:

```
if (text.contains("of")) {
```

or

```
if (text.indexOf("of") >= 0) {
```

to find out if your string *contains* "of".

And to answer your question in the title: **absolutely** yes. Programming is about being a good **craftsman** to a very large degree. A good craftsman keeps all his tools and materials **in order**. He doesn't allow for mess, waste, ...

So, long story short: from day **one**, to all eternity: when writing code, you strive for a **zero tolerance** policy: no compiler errors, no warnings, nothing in your code that doesn't belong there!

Comment: But I also want to get the position of 'of'.

Comment: And guess what the second suggestion with *indexOf* is returning? The Index aka position of the string provided as argument to that call!